Issues with Sending Video Files and Form Data from Flutter to Express Server Using Dio/Http Packages, android phone attached debugg mode
I’m having trouble uploading a video file and associated form data from my Flutter app to an Express server. Despite using both the Dio and http packages for HTTP requests, the server logs show that the file and form data are empty. Below are the details:
this is the flutter code - dart
   Future<void> _uploadVideo() async {
   if (_video == null) return;
   //   request.fields['email'] = "test@gmail.com"; // Add your email field
   //   request.files.add(await http.MultipartFile.fromPath('file', _video!.path,
   //       filename: basename(_video!.path)));

   final dio = Dio();
   const uri = 'http://192.168.1.8:3000/upload';
   var data = FormData.fromMap({
   'files': [
   await MultipartFile.fromFile(_video!.path,
   filename: basename(_video!.path))
   ],
   'email': 'savioalwd@gmail.com'
   });
   try {
   final response = await dio.request(
   uri,
   data: data,
   options: Options(method: 'POST', responseType: ResponseType.json),
  }
// the server code is 
    router.post('/upload', (req, res) => {
    console.log('Headers:', req.headers); // Log headers
    console.log('Body:', req.body); // Log form fields
    console.log('File:', req.files);
    console.log('File:', req.get('email')); // Log uploaded file
    });

// and the response from the server IS

  headers: {
  'user-agent': 'Dart/3.4 (dart:io)',
  'content-type': 'multipart/form-data; boundary=--dio-boundary-1809956562',
  'accept-encoding': 'gzip',
   'content-length': '129',
  host: '192.168.1.8:3000'
  }
  Body: {}
  File: undefined
  File: undefined

Issue
In both the Dio and http packages implementations, the server logs show that the file and form data are empty. The logs indicate:
Headers: contain the correct multipart boundary.
Body: is empty.
File: is undefined.
Troubleshooting Steps Taken
Checked File Path: Verified that _video!.path is correct.
Verified Content Type: Ensured the correct MIME type and content type were set.
Server Configuration: Checked that the multer configuration is correct for handling multipart form data.
Request for Help
Possible Issues: Are there any issues with how the form data is being constructed or sent?
Debugging Tips: What additional debugging steps can I take to resolve this issue?
Examples: Can you provide a working example of uploading a file and form data from Flutter to an Express server using Dio or http?
Thank you for any assistance!

Hi, Can you please show Multer config and upload codes as well ? We need to spot the side which fails, whether is it the backend or or the frontend. Therefore please try a simple formdata as this formData.append("username", "Chris"), this alone, from the front and see if the body gets populated. If not, then the backend needs to be checked further.

I tried with Postman and working fine. But when using Flutter Dart the api hitting to the server , but no payload @WeDoTheBest4You

Thank you for your response. To debug, please try an upload as the answer of this post says: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67580972/how-to-send-formdata-with-dio  It is expected to have the payload to reach server.

This question is similar to: node js multer file upload not working. req.file and req.files always undefined. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

use base64 encoding for the files instead flutter multipartfile method.
Read file as bytes and encode to base64. lang:dart
    List<int> fileBytes = await File(filePath).readAsBytes();
    String base64Video = base64Encode(fileBytes);

    // Create request payload
    Map<String, dynamic> payload = {
      'email': 'test@gmail.com.com',
      'userId': '0001',
      'file': base64Video,
      'fileName': fileName,
      'mimeType': mimeType,
    };

then at the server end Decode base64 string to binary data. lang:express.js
   const binaryData = Buffer.from(file, 'base64');
   const uploadPath = path.join(__dirname, "../videos", fileName);
   fs.writeFileSync(uploadPath, binaryData);


This answer is identical to this answer that you posted, the same day. In the future, please provide a reference link in your answer.
